# problem in ram in fpga zynq 7020, someone can give me advice?

Tags: fpga, ram

Hello I get a strange message when I try to run the MAP, I set the RAM properly and also checked that it uses only 80% of the resources I have on the card. Why do I get this message? Can anyone advise me what to do? And why do I have this message?

The error i got when i try to Synthesize the label "map" to get a bit file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ3yd.png) - summery of the resources.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAYZh.png)

ERROR:Place:543 - This design does not fit into the number of slices available
in this device due to the complexity of the design and/or constraints.

Unplaced instances by type:

BLOCKRAM 77 (55.0)

Please evaluate the following:

1. BLOCKRAM
   u_xyz2lcd_for_test/u_send_to_zedboard/dpr_2/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativeb
   mg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[6].ram.r/v6_noinit.ram/NO_BMM_INFO.S
   DP.SIMPLE_PRIM18.ram
2. BLOCKRAM

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that you want to use more RAM then the device has.

I suggest you check your resources again and check the amount of ***memory*** used.

Your 80% may be LUTs or FFs or you may have read something wrong.

---

There is another possibility although it is very rare:
You memory usage may increase in Place And Route if it has to split the memory over multiple blocks because you have some weird configuration.

This example may not be valid bit it tries to show what can happen:
Suppose you use bit-write enables. Synthesis thinks you have enough memory but PAR has to use a byte for each bit, thus PAR needs to splits the data over more blocks and in the end runs out.

The case where I have seen this was a very complex one with DSPs.

Comment: Hi I checked it several times, attached image. For some reason, its gives me this error, even though I have not used all the resources.                        I have attached an image to my question with the number of resources that the code takes form the borad i using.